# Django unique_together with df.to_sql not working

Tags: django, sqlalchemy

I am using `df.to_sql` to insert data into database table. But I don't want to have some duplicated rows for some columns. I tried `unique_together` but it doesn't seem working.

```
class InsertionOrdersRealSpents(InsertionOrdersCommonFields):

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s" % self.insertion_order
        # return "{}".format(self.insertion_order)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'InserstionOrdersRealSpents'
        unique_together = ['date', 'advertiser', 'dsp',
            'insertion_order', 'impressions']
```

Any method or suggestion?

If there is identical row in the database, skip that row in the file to upload ?

Comment: Did you make migrations and migrate?

Comment: My bad. I didn't migrate. After migrating, it works . Thanks